# How to keep form data in PHP?

Tags: php, xhtml

I want to keep users data when they click submit. But it said  "Undefined index"
this is my code and my screenshoot error program.
what is wrong with my code?

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<table width="300" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="kode" id="kode">
                <option>-- Silahkan Pilih --</option>
                <option value="A01" <?php if ($_POST[kode]=="A01") echo "selected";?>>A01 - Speaker</option>
                <option value="B02" <?php if ($_POST[kode]=="B02") echo "selected";?>>B02 - Mouse</option>
                <option value="C03" <?php if ($_POST[kode]=="C03") echo "selected";?>>C03 - Harddisk</option>
                <option value="D04" <?php if ($_POST[kode]=="D04") echo "selected";?>>D04 - Mouse</option>
            </select></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Jumlah Beli</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" value="<?php echo $_POST[jumlah];?>" /> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="status_member" id="member" value="member" <?php if ($_POST[status_member]=="member") echo "checked";?> />
            Member
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="status_member" id="member" value="bukan_member" <?php if ($_POST[status_member]=="bukan_member") echo "checked";?> />
            Bukan Member</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kota Kirim</td>
        <td>
            <select name="kota_kirim" id="Kota">
                <option>--Silahkan Pilih Kota --</option>
                <option value="Jakarta" <?php if ($_POST[kota_kirim]=="Jakarta") echo "selected";?>>Jakarta</option>
                <option value="Bandung" <?php if ($_POST[kota_kirim]=="Bandung") echo "selected";?>>Bandung</option>
                <option value="Padang" <?php if ($_POST[kota_kirim]=="Padang") echo "selected";?>>Padang</option>
                <option value="Yogyakarta" <?php if ($_POST[kota_kirim]=="Yogyakarta") echo "selected";?>>Yogyakarta</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <center><input type="submit" name="Hitung" id="Hitung" value="Hitung" />
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" /></center>
</p>
</form>
<?php if($_POST[Hitung]=="Hitung") {?>
<?php ...
```

but I got this error messages when I load it
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use quotes, e.g.:

```
if($_POST["Hitung"]=="Hitung")
```

Edit. And first check if the key exists:

```
if ((isset($_POST["Hitung"]) && ($_POST["Hitung"] == "Hitung"))
```

Comment: And actually you also have to check if the key exists, which is not the case if you load the page without a POST. (array_key_exists)

Comment: i have try it but still error
Undefined index: Hitung in

Answer (score 1):

You need to check all post data by `isset()`  and then check your condition

You also need use quotes for post data name. if you not use quotes then it will be treated as constant(e.g in your notice it says undefined constant).

like this:

```
  if (isset($_POST['status_member']) && $_POST['status_member']=="member")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put quotes on all of your $_POST request, please try this (and i suggest you to check if your variable exist before using 'isset' :

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<table width="300" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="kode" id="kode">
                <option>-- Silahkan Pilih --</option>
                <option value="A01" <?php if ($_POST["kode"]=="A01") echo "selected";?>>A01 - Speaker</option>
                <option value="B02" <?php if ($_POST["kode"]=="B02") echo "selected";?>>B02 - Mouse</option>
                <option value="C03" <?php if ($_POST["kode"]=="C03") echo "selected";?>>C03 - Harddisk</option>
                <option value="D04" <?php if ($_POST["kode"]=="D04") echo "selected";?>>D04 - Mouse</option>
            </select></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Jumlah Beli</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" value="<?php echo $_POST["jumlah"];?>" /> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="status_member" id="member" value="member" <?php if ($_POST["status_member"]=="member") echo "checked";?> />
            Member
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="status_member" id="member" value="bukan_member" <?php if ($_POST["status_member"]=="bukan_member") echo "checked";?> />
            Bukan Member</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kota Kirim</td>
        <td>
            <select name="kota_kirim" id="Kota">
                <option>--Silahkan Pilih Kota --</option>
                <option value="Jakarta" <?php if ($_POST["kota_kirim"]=="Jakarta") echo "selected";?>>Jakarta</option>
                <option value="Bandung" <?php if ($_POST["kota_kirim"]=="Bandung") echo "selected";?>>Bandung</option>
                <option value="Padang" <?php if ($_POST["kota_kirim"]=="Padang") echo "selected";?>>Padang</option>
                <option value="Yogyakarta" <?php if ($_POST["kota_kirim"]=="Yogyakarta") echo "selected";?>>Yogyakarta</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <center><input type="submit" name="Hitung" id="Hitung" value="Hitung" />
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" /></center>
</p>
</form>
<?php ((isset($_POST["Hitung"]) && ($_POST["Hitung"] == "Hitung")) {?>
<?php ...
```

Comment: I have try it before I ask here, and it still show error.
issets solved it but I must change my code because like you said no variable exist

thank you